# React: Fade not working

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm using this code from here: http://buildwithreact.com/article/fade-in-image-recipe

currently have it as my component:

```
<ImageComponent src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7NFV6Nnpkalk5cEU" />
```

Now when I go to google chrome and inspect the element, it has the class names of `image` and `image-loaded` but when take a look at the css, there is no css even though I added it to my style sheet. Does anyone know how to fix this?

```
.image { opacity: 0;   transition: opacity 500ms ease-in; }
.imageloaded { opacity: 1; }
```

Here is the css I imported(code above)

```
 import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ImageComponent from './image.component.jsx';
import styles from './css/Header.css';


    export default class Home extends Component {


     constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          lightboxIsOpen: false,
          currentImage: 0,
        }

        this.closeLightbox = this.closeLightbox.bind(this);
        this.gotoNext = this.gotoNext.bind(this);
        this.gotoPrevious = this.gotoPrevious.bind(this);

      }

      return(
        <div>

    <Grid>
        <div>
                    <ImageComponent src="https://docs.google.com/uc?id=0B0huBtqYaof7NFV6Nnpkalk5cEU" />

    </div>
    </Grid>
    </div>


        )
    }
```

Here is the component for ImageComponent

```
import classNames from 'classnames';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ReactDOM, { render } from 'react-dom';



const ImageComponent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      loaded: false
    };
  },

  onImageLoad: function() {
    if (this.isMounted()) {
      this.setState({ loaded: true });
    }
  },

  componentDidMount: function() {
    var imgTag = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.img);
    var imgSrc = imgTag.getAttribute('src');
    var img = new window.Image();
    img.onload = this.onImageLoad;
    img.src = imgSrc;
  },

  render: function() {
    var { className, ...props } = this.props;
    var imgClasses = 'image';
    var rootClassName = classNames(className, 'image', {
      'imageloaded': this.state.loaded,
    });

    return (
      <img ref="img" {...props} className={rootClassName} />
    );
  }
});

export default ImageComponent;
```

Comment: The [JSbin](http://jsbin.com/velakevahi/1/embed?css,js,output) given from the post work well :  so I think you are missing something in your code. Could you share it ?

Comment: @soywod I edited my post to include the code. I gutted out some of the reactbootstrap stuff and other things I had inthere to just this image. Do you think it has to do with the css file? react way of using css is className={style.doThis} right? but when I take a look at the ImageComponent code it doesn't have that "style" or file name that i'm directing it to. I'm not sure if that is the problem

Answer (score 1):

Try passing image url as props to imagecomponent and directly attach it to img element.